# Best way to store a log and send newest activities to client browser in realtime

Tags: php, logging, console

I want to create logging/console utility accesible from web, where I can check in realtime some basic status of domains, see last PHP and Apache errors and warning messages and so on.

My question, aside from implementation of above features, is how to store that log data, and how to pull it from server with minimum traffic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirements seem to have a perfect fit in HTTP Push technologies. If you are in control of the client (i.e. you know it will be a modern, standard-compliant browser) you can use the offical W3C [EventSource](http://dev.w3.org/html5/eventsource/) or [WebSockets](http://www.indicthreads.com/1525/building-real-time-web-applications-using-html-5-web-sockets/). Otherwise, you'd have to poll at regular intervals using AJAX or just refresh every 15 seconds.

About the storage itself, the cleanest solution would be if you directly store your logs in MySQL ([Apache guide](http://www.howtoforge.com/apache2-logging-to-a-mysql-database-with-mod_log_sql-on-debian-etch)). If you feel inspired to try something new, you could experiment with NoSQL databases, but I don't have much experience there.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. But, in case of older browser, is there any optimization technique for minimalizing traffic and lag?

Comment: Yes, if you use AJAX you can transfer only the messages without refreshing the whole site. The lag will still be the same, however it won't be so irritating.

Comment: Your answer looks correct, but what about storing log?

Comment: I thought about MySQL, but it seemed to be a bit overkill. Whole idea of NoSQL fits pretty well for my project. Thank you for help!